# What is the max size of subset of a Hamming Space with this property

Tags: metric-spaces, coding-theory

Keep in mind I know virtually no coding theory, I simply recognized this as an equivalent formulation to another question I was considering.

Let $F(r,n)$ denote the set of all words of length $r$ on $n$ letters.  and let $H(f,g)$ be the Hamming distance between $f$ and $g$.

What I wish to know is the following:

For fixed integers $r,n,k$ what is the maximum possible cardinality of $S \subset F(r,n)$ with the property that $ \forall f,g \in S$, $H(f,g) \ge k$.

Any information you can give me about this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general your question has no complete answer. Even if you are in the case that $n=q$ is a prime power the answer is very hard in general.

However, when the size of the alphabet is a prime power you could have a look at some bounds on the maximum possible cardinality of $S$ here

Some upper bounds

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griesmer_bound

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_bound

A lower bound

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Varshamov_bound

Comment: Thank you this gives me something to go on.  When you say "no complete answer" do you mean that it has been proven no exact formula exists or that it simply hasn't been found yet?

Of particular interest to me here is the Singleton bound, I had actually proven this before I even heard of the Hamming distance.  Do you know of any examples where this inequality is strict? Because all the examples I have looked at have the number exactly equal to this bound

Comment: I believe that there is not a closed formula that looks nice. It depends on many factors.
With your notation an example where the Singleton bound is strict should be $n=2, r=6, k=3$. You can see that with these parameters the singleton bound is $16$, while the Plotkin bound gives $8$